# java link two classes together

Tags: java

This is a very simple java code for shop, allowing user to purchase few items.

In another class (tamagotchi pet class), I have created a `feed()` method, which one of the function will be to --food to show usage of the items purchased in the shop.

How do I link both classes to add this function to my `feed()` method?

```
Shop Class: 

public class Shop {


int balance = 80;
int reward = 100;
int dumplingsMEAL = 1;
int beddingPACK = 1;
int toy = 1;
int dumplingsPrice = 20;
int beddingPrice = 40;
int toyPrice = 10;
int food = 1;
int bedding = 1;
int toys = 1;

public void earnReward () {
    balance = balance + reward;
}

public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

public void purchaseDumplings() {
    balance = balance - dumplingsPrice;
    ++food;
}

public void purchaseBedding() {
    balance = balance - beddingPrice;
    ++bedding;
}

public void purchaseToy() {
    balance = balance - toyPrice;
    ++ toys;
}
}
```

Comment: Why dont you create the object for that class and use its methods here

Comment: read about inheritance ... else ... make the feed method static and do something like...
MyClass.feed();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `tamagotchi pet class`, Create a new Method `Feed()` and here create the Object Of `Shop` class. Now with the help of reference variable you can access all `Shop` class member function.

```
public void feed() {
    Shop shop = new Shop();
    shop.earnReward();
    shop.getBalance();
    shop.purchaseDumplings();
    shop.purchaseToy();
}
```

Comment: can i Create a new shop outside the method so it can apply to other methods as well? because I have methods such as play(), sleep() that need amending also.

Comment: Off Course, You can :)

Comment: If satisfied, Mark the answer as Tick :)